# ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 MySQL database with regions

Tags: database, iso, iso-3166

I'm trying to create two different tables with ISO 3166 2 code database for countries and trying to add a custom field with regions (North America, Europe, South America, etc).

I've been trying to find out if there is any open project or data with this info but still no luck.

If anyone could throw me a bone here it would be great.

Regards,

Pablo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ISO 6166-2 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) defines administrative regions, ie 2nd-level regions for countries. This might be what you are looking for.

The ISO database can be obtained from various sources:

- http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm
- http://www.geopostcodes.com/GeoPC_ISO_3166_2_Regions_codes
- http://blog.bakedproject.com/2009/12/27/iso-3166-iso-3166-1-iso-3166-2/

Once you have the data in MySql, it should be quite easy to add columns you need.